# Crack Hashed Byte Array?

Tags: hash, password-cracking

I know it would take forever to crack a simple hashed byte array, though for learning sake I was wondering whether it is possible to crack a hashed byte array?

And if so, any suggestions how to do it?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Cracking tools like hashcat have a brute-force mode that allows you to specify a mask.  One of the available masks is for binary data, so you could use that to attempt to crack your hash.

Something like:

```
hashcat --attack-mode 3 --increment hash.txt ?b?b?b?b?b?b?b?b
```

You'll still need to specify `--hash-type`, but you can find the appropriate value from hashcat's help page.